# iPhone reverse device orientation in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, screen-rotation

here's a weird question,
Is there a way to inverse the device orientation of the iPhone in cocos2d?
ex:
if the device is held in a landscape left position, i want the screen to show the landscape right and vice-versa.
so basically to let the device work in the opposite way of its intended use.
Thank you.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a game where you want to invert the gravity of the world, I'd suggest you doing this without tweaking device orientation, but by changing gravity vector direction instead.

Comment: basically the idea is to use inverted graphics in the game, like istabilise the player a bit, it's an upside down world. Although I am not using chipmunk or box2d, I did manage to change the director's orientation to uUpsideDown portrait and it did the trick, but I am not sure if this is the best solution to do so.